# Parsing a large exponential number in .NET

Tags: c#, parsing

I am trying to convert some Java code into C# and ran across an issue with parsing very large exponential numbers in .NET.

The number I am trying to parse is `"1.79769313486232E+308"`.

I have tried using both double (which is what is used in the code I am translating) and decimal, but both throw an overflow exception that the number is too large.

```
double result = double.Parse("1.79769313486232E+308",
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I have tried various other combinations as well, such as using `NumberStyles.Any`.

This is working fine in Java. But before I attempt to convert the [code from Java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29), I was hoping that there is another (native) option in .NET. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like this particular piece of code is referring to the maximum possible `double` value, so why not use `double.MaxValue` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger result = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("1.79769313486232E+308", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

You can try [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) you should add reference to `System.Numerics` in your project

**EDIT**

Because of the comments, current number can be represented by int(**without losing any information**) because it is integer itself. This is scientific notation so how this translates. For an example:

```
1.23E+11 or as 1.23 X 10^11
```

So in his case:

```
1.79769313486232E+308 = 1.79769313486232*10^308
```

Which is away from double boundaries and can be written as biginteger. The number is integer itself so there is no problem!

Comment: It parses into a BigInteger fine, but when I cast it back to a double, it becomes `Infinity` rather than the number I am looking for.

Comment: Never mind. That is because I am losing precision somewhere (some code apparently didn't use the "R" (round-trip) option when converting to a string in the first place, so it is out of range for a double - I think this will work if I can find that other piece of code.

Comment: Yes you are out of range of double.

Comment: Really? Using `BigInteger` to parse a `double`? What is the result if you parse "3.14159"?

Comment: @Henrik - `1.79769313486232E+308` isn't a `double`. It's a very big integer.

Comment: @Enigmativity  I assume OP needs a function that can parse doubles and just dosen't throw in the given special case.

Comment: @Henrik - that is true. Unfortunately, this is the only option I have found that works so far - maybe a .NET bug?

Comment: @Henrik look what is scientific notation : https://www.nyu.edu/pages/mathmol/textbook/scinot.html

Comment: @NightOwl888 I wouldn't call it a bug, it is documented to behave that way. But I think it's an unfortunate design decision.

Comment: @Henrik 1.23E+11 or as 1.23 X 10^11  which is integer there is no poor design decision ...

Comment: It is documented that you can convert a `double.MaxValue` to a string, but cannot parse it back to a double (or even a decimal)? Where is that documented?

Comment: @NightOwl888 the number you are trying to parse is slightly greater than `double.MaxValue`. See Emad's answer.

Comment: @mybirthname `double.Parse` throws, if the number is greater then `double.MaxValue`. I would prefer it to return `double.Inifinity`. That's the design decision I'm talking about.

Comment: Right, which is why I need to use round trip (as I already pointed out). `double.Parse(double.MaxValue.ToString("R"))`. Now I see where I went wrong - the number didn't have a `+` sign before the exponent in Java, so when I tried to parse `1.7976931348623157E308` to double it doesn't work, but `1.7976931348623157E+308` (which is what round-trip gives you in .NET) works fine.

Comment: @NightOwl888 the + sign doesn't make a difference, the number in your screenshot is different from the number of your initial question.
1.79769313486232E+308 is different from 1.7976931348623157E+308

Comment: And *again* the reason why the number is different is because the code didn't specify round-trip when converting it to string in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, I am marking this as the correct answer. Although I don't need to resort to System.Numerics.BigInteger to solve this if anyone *really* wants to parse a number that is out of range of double, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is too large bro.

Double can hold up to:
1.7976931348623157E+308

See: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14004444)

Comment: I have answered the problem mentioned in the question:

Comment: The problem was that double.parse throws "an overflow exception" and that's because the number in question is bigger than double.maxvalue. Is there anything wrong with what I said because I want to know if there is.

Comment: Topic starter asked for another (native) option in .NET to parse number, bigger than max double.